# JPanel adding background

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

How to resize the inputpanel and gamepanel so it can take the whole frame? the inputpanel.setsize() wont work and the other problem is that the gamepanel wont display its  background image.

what I did is I added a mainpanel to the frame that contains the other 2 panel the inputpanel and the gamepanel. Both panels displays with their borders but the size is very small and I needed them to fit the screen

```
public class GameMaster   {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel gamepanel  = new Gamepanel();
            JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Hoy!");

            public GameMaster(){

                frame.setTitle("gayEdward vs Charlie's angels");
                frame.setSize(800,600);

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


                gamepanel.setSize(600, 600);
                inputpanel.setSize(200, 600);
                mainpanel.setSize(800, 600);
                gamepanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                inputpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


                mainpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());




                mainpanel.add(gamepanel);
                mainpanel.add(inputpanel);


                frame.add(mainpanel);

            }
```

This is the Gamepanel class where The Gamepanel should set the image as its background

```
    public class Gamepanel extends JPanel {
        Image image;

        public Gamepanel(){

             try
                {
                  image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\phg00159\\workspace\\Mp2\\pvzbg.jpg"));;
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /*handled in paintComponent()*/ }

        }


          protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
          {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            if (image != null)
              g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `BorderLayout` `mainpanel` and `gamepanel`.  Add the `gamepanel` to the `mainpanel` and the `inputpanel` to the `gamepanel`...

Comment: `Gamepanel` MUST return a preferred size in order to be layout correctly.  Override the `getPreferredSize` and return the "default" size you would like to use for the panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `getPreferredSize()` in the `GamePanel` class. You should always do this when doing custom painting. The panel has no preferred size because it has no components. And the layout you are using `FlowLayout` takes the preferred size into consideration. Then just `pack()` the frame, instead of setting the size. Also note that `setSize()` for components is generally used for null layouts (which I strongly am against). With layout managers, they are determine by `preferredSize`

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
        // or whatever you want the size to be
    }
}
```

Aside:

- `/*handled in paintComponent()*/` - A null check isn't a substitute for an empty catch block.
- `frame.setVisible()` should the *last* thing you do after adding all your components

---

**UPDATE**

As @MadProgrammer pointed out to me, you want the panel to resize with the frame. In order to do that, you need to use a different layout manager. The two that *won't* respect the preferred size of your panels will be either `GridLayout` or `BorderLayout`. These will "stretch your components to fit". So choose one of them, or a combination of both, seeing as you have nested panels. But you should also keep the overriden `getPreferredSize()` and still `pack()` your frame This will give you the initial size of the frame, based on your preferred size

Comment: The OP is also using a `FlowLayout`, which will layout components side by size...

Comment: @MadProgrammer The fact that the OP said "but the size is very small", I'm thinking the size is not taken into account. Should be preferred size that's calculated, no?

Comment: *"How to resize the inputpanel and gamepanel so it can take the whole frame?"* - But, yes, you point is valid, just not complete ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, there I go again _skimming_ ;-) I'll add that.

Comment: Yeah, you can kinda see why I "skipped" it ;)

Comment: sorry but I cant understand the override part im just new in java. could you post some code? thanks

Comment: @PNC see my edit. All I did was just put that method in your `GamePanel` class. You don't ever have to call it. The layout manager will call it for you. I basically just made the panel the size of the image. If you want the panel bigger, just specify your own size (width, height)

Comment: @PNC has this answer solved your question? Peeskillet has put effort into helping you so if your question is resolved, please consider marking this answer as accepted. (Of course, it's okay if you're not comfortable with this answer. A single SO question shouldn't turn into a supervised debugging session, and you're not required to accept an answer, especially if you have trouble with it.)